# $\int \frac{dx}{x^3+x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}-x}$

Tags: integration

solve:
$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x^3+x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}-x}$$
I tried:
$$\begin{align}\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x(x^2-1)+x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}&=\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x(\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1})+x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\&=\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x)}\end{align}$$

$x=\sin t$
$$\int \frac{\mathrm dt}{\cos t\sin t-\sin^2t}$$
And I can not continue from here.

Comment: Should I use $x=sint$ ?

Comment: Could also try x=cosh(t) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can proceed from where you are like this, e.g.

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x\right)} =\\
&=&-\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\\
&=&-\int\frac1xdx +\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\\
&=&-\log|x|+\log\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x\right)+C
\end{eqnarray}

**EDIT**
For the second integral use $t=\cosh x$, recalling that $\sinh^2 x= \cosh^2-1$, and $\operatorname{arccosh} x=\log(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x)$.

**EDIT 2**
Alternatively, as in comment, $x = \sec t$, brings the second integral to  $\int \sec t dt =\log(\tan t + \sec t) + C= \log(\sqrt{\sec^2t-1}+\sec t)+C\dots$

Comment: You can simplify it further to $\log\left(\left|\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+1\right|\right) + C$.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question How you solved $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$? did you use $x=sect$   another answer for this integral is -Arcsin(x) right?

Comment: @hgs Another way: substitute $x = \sec t$ to get $\int\frac{\sec t\tan t + \sec^2t}{\tan t + \sec t}\mathrm dt$, and then substitute $r = \tan t  + \sec t$.

Comment: @hgs i just used $t=\operatorname{cosh}x$.

Comment: @hgs In fact I have used $x=\sec(t)$ :-) with another way.

Comment: @hgs, No I don't think you can write it with $-\arcsin x$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Put $x＝\dfrac{1}{\cos t}$, then 
$$\int \frac{\cos^3 t}{\sin t(\sin t+1)}\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2 t}dt＝\int \frac{d\sin t}{\sin t+1}$$

Comment: That doesn't look correct. Can you double-check your working?

Comment: @an4s I think it's correct.

Comment: This is a beautiful substitution !   (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can try with $x=\sec(t)$ with a trigonometric substitution. With this substitution you will obtain $$\int \frac{1}{\sec (t)+\tan (t)}dt=\int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos (t)}+\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos (t)}}dt$$
After another substitution $t=1+\sin (u)$ and $u=\mathrm{arcsec}(x)$ you will try the solution of the integral.